# Issue using JEST for mongoDB operations testing

Tags: javascript, mongodb, testing, jestjs

I want to write unit/integration tests but it does not work when I call my function insertOneObject and I don't understand why the collection is undefined.
Resource used: https://jestjs.io/fr/docs/mongodb
https://github.com/shelfio/jest-mongodb

````
export const insertOneObject = async (dbCollection, object) => {
  try {
    await db.collection(dbCollection).insertOne(object);
    console.log(`Successfully inserted object`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to insert object: ${error}`);
    throw error;
  }
};

//test.js
import {
  insertOneObject,
} from "../../src/services/buildCollection.js";

describe("mongo operations", () => {
  let connection;
  let db;
  let javaMockCollection;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    connection = await MongoClient.connect(global.__MONGO_URI__, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    db = connection.db(globalThis.__MONGO_DB_NAME__);
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    javaMockCollection = db.collection("java-mock-collection");
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await connection.close();
  });

//this works
  test("should insert a doc into collection", async () => {
    const mockObj= { name: "objname" };

    await javaMockCollection.insertOne(mockObj);

    const insertedObj = await tps.findOne({ name: "objname" });
    expect(insertedObj).toEqual(mockObj);
  }); 

//this does not work
// Failed to insert object: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')
test("should insert a doc into collection", async () => {
    const mockObj= { name: "objname" };

    await insertOneObject("java-mock-collection", mockObj);

    const insertedObj = await tps.findOne({ name: "objname" });
    expect(insertedObj ).toEqual(mockObj);
  }); 
});```
````